# Windows 8 laptop shuts down right after startup

Tags: boot, windows-8, shutdown, hp-laptop, intel-atom

Today Windows Update installed some new updates on my laptop,everything was good,the installation was 100% complete and then my it restarted my laptop.Right when i was about to type my password it shut down.I turned it on again and the same thing happened,no matter how many times i start it up it shuts down right when i get to the login screen or after i manage to type my password and see the desktop.
For now i'm on safe mode,i ran the SFC scan,DISM and startup repair but none of them worked,is there something else i can do?

Comment: Get the Manufacturer's Hardware Test App and run that. Safe Mode runs in limited memory. You could have a memory error or other hardware error. Try that and see what it tells you.

Comment: Do you have a disk image from before the update? Have you tried uninstalling the update? Have you tried rolling back to a Restore point?

Comment: Have you tried going into safe mode and uninstalling the most recently installed update?